# Le Gall Exercise 1.4

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I try to make exercise 1.4 from the book Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes written by Le Gall. I need to prove the following.

Let $(E, \mathscr{A}, μ)$ be a measure space, with $μ(E) > 0$, and let $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Show that, for every $ε > 0$, there exists a measurable set $A ∈ \mathscr{A}$ such that $\mu(A) > 0$ and $|f (x) − f (y)| < \varepsilon$ for every $x, y ∈ A$.

I have the following ideas:

- Define $A_n = \{x,y \in \mathscr{A} : |f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{1}{n}\}$. Then $ A = \cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n$. Since f is measurable, we know A_n is measurable for all n. Therefore $A$ is measurable.
- I also know that $A_n \supseteq A_{n+1}$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n) = \mu(A)$.

I don't know how to show that $\mu(A) >0$. I think it helps to work with proof by conrtradiction. How can I use that $\mu(E) > 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your sets $A$ are not subsets of $E$ but of $E\times E$ (they have two components ). I think that if you write $f$ as the pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions, the whole thing will follow. Recall that, at least for $f\geq0$, $f=\lim s_n$ where $s_n=\sum^{2^nn}_{j=0}k2^{-n}\mathbb{1}(k2^{-n}\leq f <(k+1)2^{-n}f)$.

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of $A_n$ is weird, it looks like a subset of $E^2$ and not $E$.

I would rather write $\mathbb R$ as a countable union of intervals of length $\varepsilon/2$, for instance $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}[n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2]$, so that $E=f^{-1}(\mathbb R)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2])$.

Then
$$
\mu(E)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2])\right)\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mu(f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2])).
$$

If you had $\mu(f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2]))=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$ then you would have that $\mu(E)=0$.

As $\mu(E)>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\mu(f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2])$). Set $A=f^{-1}([n\varepsilon/2,(n+1)\varepsilon/2])$. Then $\mu(A)>0$ and for all $x,y\in A$, $\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert\le\frac\varepsilon2<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! How can I proceed / answering the exercise? :)

Comment: Show that one of the sets if the countable union must have positive measure

Comment: hmmmm, I don't really get it :(

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!